# Having a <Textarea> with a max buffer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have seen plenty of code snippets to force a `<Textarea>` to have only X number of characters and then not allow anymore. What I am in need of is a `<Textarea>` where you can specify how many characters I can have at one time at most. Almost like a max buffer size. Think of it like a rolling log file. I want to always show the last/newest X number of characters.

Simpler the solution the better. I am not a web expert so the more complicated it gets the more greek it looks to me. :)

I am already using jQuery so a solution with that should be ok.

Comment: You need to specify whether you want to *show* the last X characters or the textarea to *contain* only the last X characters. In DOM terms, should the element content be truncated (to last X chars), or should the rendering mechanism (somehow) limit the visibility?

Comment: Sorry by 'show' I meant I want the textarea to contain the last/newest X number of characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<textarea id="yourTextArea" data-maxchars="1000"></textarea>

var textarea = document.getElementById('yourTextArea');

var taChanged = function(e){       
   var ta = e.target;
   var maxChars = ta.getAttribute('data-maxchars');
   if(ta.value.length > maxChars){
      ta.value = ta.value.substr(0,maxChars);
   }
}
textarea.addEventListener('change', taChanged, 1);
```

for the last chars:

```
 ta.value = ta.value.substr(ta.value.length - 1000);
```

Comment: Just viewing the code.. wouldnt that keep the the first 1000 characters? I need the LAST 1000 characters.

Comment: you want to keep the last chars? so change the line, as edited above

Comment: Using what Andre has done and changing it to last 1000 characters shouldn't be too difficult. As you understood the answer, why don't you just change the relevant line. As described in Wills answer. Don't be lazy and expect others to do your job!

Answer (score 1):

And jQuery implementation:

```
$('#text').keyup(function() {
    var max = $(this).data('maxchars'),
        len = $(this).val().length;

    len > max && $(this).val(function() {
        return $(this).val().substr(len - max);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WsnSk/

Answer (score 0):

No code, I can't even spell JavaScript, but basically as you're about to add new text, check the length of the existing text. If the old text plus the new text is too long, trim off the beginning of the old text (likely at a newline or whatever). Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Why down vote? This is a perfectly good answer. Just because it doesn't include code?

Comment: I can't even spell downvote but basically this answer is not useful or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code [on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/XxdhG/). It uses Jquery to make it simple.

```
<textarea id="txtArea"></textarea>


var size = 5;

$('#txtArea').change(function(){
    var strValue = $('#txtArea').val();
    strValue = strValue.split("").reverse().join("").substring(0, size).split("").reverse().join("");
    alert(strValue);
});
```